# Matching strings between 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

In my PHP example below I have Item data and Amount data - How could I get it to output

`Item 1 23` etc

**PHP:**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Item 1"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "item 2"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "item 3"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "23"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "90"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "23"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$item = array("Item 1","item 2","item 3") ;
$amount = array("23","90","23") ;

foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
    $result_array[] = $value." ".$amount[$key];
}
print_r($result_array);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Item 1 23
    [1] => item 2 90
    [2] => item 3 23
)
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Either using **[array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)** if you need to have one array of it.</strike>

`array_combine($array1, $array2)`
will create something like:

```
array(3) {
  [23]=>
  string(6) "Item 1"
  [90]=>
  string(6) "item 2"
  [23]=>
  string(6) "item 3"
}
```

Or, if you want just to echo the values, **foreach()** it!

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
  echo $array2[$key] . ": " . $value;
}
```

Comment: Would fail as two items would attempt to share the same key.